# iis wcf authenticate_request bad request

Tags: wcf, iis

Please help.

We have a WCF web service that is accepting calls via JSON from iOS. Sporadically, we get a 400 Bad Request error. After searching for this error, the only solution that I could find is that the size limit was reached, but our calls are really small (like 50 characters small). This doesn't happen every time, usually only 40-50 times per day, but it's enough to cause some major problems. We turned on request tracing, but the XML doesn't give us much information to investigate. Does anyone know what could be causing this? Attached is one of the request log files.

Thanks in advance.

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>4</Level>
  <Opcode>38</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-01-14T13:46:41.851Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="16572" ThreadID="17048"/>
  <Computer>DED2768</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}</Data>
  <Data Name="BytesReceived">50</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_READ_ENTITY_END</Opcode>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>51</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x0</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-01-14T13:46:41.851Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="16572" ThreadID="17048"/>
  <Computer>DED2768</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}</Data>
  <Data Name="Buffer">{&quot;hub&quot;:&quot;(null)&quot;, &quot;co&quot;:&quot;OCALFLXA&quot;, &quot;eci&quot;:&quot;CNUCAJP&quot;}</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>GENERAL_REQUEST_ENTITY</Opcode>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{D42CF7EF-DE92-473E-8B6C-621EA663113A}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="ASPNET" Guid="{AFF081FE-0247-4275-9C4E-021F3DC1DA35}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>0</Version>
  <Level>5</Level>
  <Opcode>11</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x2</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-01-14T13:47:10.228Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="16572" ThreadID="17048"/>
  <Computer>DED2768</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ConnID">0</Data>
  <Data Name="Context ID">{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}</Data>
  <Data Name="Data1">System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule</Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>AspNetPipelineLeave</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>Module</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{06A01367-79D3-4594-8EB3-C721603C4679}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
 <System>
  <Provider Name="WWW Server" Guid="{3A2A4E84-4C21-4981-AE10-3FDA0D9B0F83}"/>
  <EventID>0</EventID>
  <Version>1</Version>
  <Level>3</Level>
  <Opcode>16</Opcode>
  <Keywords>0x100</Keywords>
  <TimeCreated SystemTime="2016-01-14T13:47:10.228Z"/>
  <Correlation ActivityID="{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}"/>
  <Execution ProcessID="16572" ThreadID="17048"/>
  <Computer>DED2768</Computer>
 </System>
 <EventData>
  <Data Name="ContextId">{00000000-0000-0000-A516-018000000058}</Data>
  <Data Name="ModuleName">ServiceModel</Data>
  <Data Name="Notification">2</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpStatus">400</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpReason">Bad Request</Data>
  <Data Name="HttpSubStatus">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ErrorCode">0</Data>
  <Data Name="ConfigExceptionInfo"></Data>
 </EventData>
 <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
  <Opcode>MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS</Opcode>
  <Keywords>
   <Keyword>RequestNotifications</Keyword>
  </Keywords>
  <freb:Description Data="Notification">AUTHENTICATE_REQUEST</freb:Description>
  <freb:Description Data="ErrorCode">The operation completed successfully.
 (0x0)</freb:Description>
 </RenderingInfo>
 <ExtendedTracingInfo xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/trace">
  <EventGuid>{002E91E3-E7AE-44AB-8E07-99230FFA6ADE}</EventGuid>
 </ExtendedTracingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: Sidelong related, when it comes to user clients I never have them touch a WCF service. They access a MVC controller that acts as a proxy to my internal network. The MVC controller will hand off the request to either an in-memory transport service or to a service bus / message queue.

Comment: Your posted log file looks like from the Windows Event Viewer. What you actually need is to enable **[Service Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)**, which will give you detailed exception / inner exceptions down to the assembly level. Otherwise it's just guesswork.

Comment: @jstreet Thanks. Enabling service tracing now to get more detailed information.